# VBA - Copy Paste value base on the header

Tags: vba, scripting, header, copy

Hello Friends & Community, I am trying to copy and paste value from one sheet to another base on the header.

For example I have **Sheet1** with Table as below

| 20200101 | 20200102 | 20200103 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 234 | 234 |
| 333 | 233 | 232 |

And **Sheet2** with Table as below

| 20200102 | 20200101 | 20200103 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

I would like my vba code to copy & paste the value from sheet1 to sheet 2 using header as reference.

Luckily I was able to find below code that execute exact operation as I wanted. But the only issue is that the header from original source(Sheet1)doesn't start at A1(row 1 column 1) as the syntax desired. Also the paste destination header doesnt start at A1 either. I tried to alter several parameter in below code but never able to get it work. If anyone can help me understand below syntax and instruct me on which parameter I need to change in order to paste correctly it will be greatly appreciated. Thank yoU!

```
Dim HeaderRow_A As Long
Dim HeaderLastColumn_A As Long
Dim TableColStart_A As Long
Dim NameList_A As Object
Dim SourceDataStart As Long
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim Source As Variant

Dim i As Long

Dim ws_B_lastCol As Long
Dim NextEntryline As Long
Dim SourceCol_A As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws_A = wb.Worksheets("WIP-RSWW1")
Set ws_B = wb.Worksheets("Base Data_RS")
Set NameList_A = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ws_A
    SourceDataStart = 2
    HeaderRow_A = 2  'set the header row in sheet A
    TableColStart_A = 2 'Set start col in sheet A
    HeaderLastColumn_A = .Cells(HeaderRow_A, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  'Get number of NAMEs you have

    For i = TableColStart_A To HeaderLastColumn_A
        If Not NameList_A.Exists(UCase(.Cells(HeaderRow_A, i).Value)) Then  'check if the name exists in the dictionary
             NameList_A.Add UCase(.Cells(HeaderRow_A, i).Value), i 'if does not exist record name as KEY and Column number as value in dictionary
        End If
    Next i

End With




With ws_B  'worksheet you want to paste data into
    ws_B_lastCol = .Cells(HeaderRow_A, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Get number of DATA you have in sheet B
    For i = 1 To ws_B_lastCol   'for each data
        SourceCol_A = NameList_A(UCase(.Cells(1, i).Value))  'get the column where the name is in Sheet A from the dictionaary

        If SourceCol_A <> 0 Then  'if 0 means the name doesnt exists
            SourceLastRow = ws_A.Cells(Rows.Count, SourceCol_A).End(xlUp).Row
            Set Source = ws_A.Range(ws_A.Cells(SourceDataStart, SourceCol_A), ws_A.Cells(SourceLastRow, SourceCol_A))
            NextEntryline = .Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'get the next entry line of the particular name in sheet A

            .Range(.Cells(NextEntryline, i), _
                   .Cells(NextEntryline, i)) _
                   .Resize(Source.Rows.Count, Source.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = Source.Cells.Value
        End If

    Next i
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: change `TableColStart_A = 2 'Set start col in sheet A` value to 1

Comment: Hello I have tried that but the code would not create any result